# Python Gtk3 Treeview filter and edit

Tags: python, treeview, gtk3

I have a tree-view which has multiple columns and rows. The cell renderer texts are editable. You can correct them. So I added a filter for finding failures easily. But when i filter and correct a row, it corrects the wrong row. So let me explain better, in my treeview rows begin from zero to hundred. But when i filter, there is only two rows and their path numbers are zero and one, their original path numbers are ten and eleven. So when i change row zero, the change function goes to treeview row zero and corrects it. How can i fix it ?

My change function.

```
    def changed(self,widget,path,text):
    self.liststore[path][self.col_len-2] = text
```

Answer (score 1):

You  can add fake index column (dumplicate real index column) for treeview .
  This way save your table index .
  treeview will work with real  or fake index column . this is your choose .  Then not change one index column for relational database

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "convert_path_to_child_path(filter_path)" function.